# git installation issue

Tags: git, macos

I get an error message when I type in the command make when I am in the current git directory, how do I fix this issue?

This is what I type in and receive:

cd git-1.7.5.4

git-1.7.5.4$ make

~bash: make: command not found.

How do I alleviate this issue so I can run the make commands for git and curl?

Comment: @yoda `git` does not use Autotools. It actually uses a handwritten Makefile and a `config.mak`.

Comment: @monadic: Yes, I overlooked the fact that he doesn't have `make` installed. XCode was probably the first thing I installed when I bought my mac, so I forgot that `make` doesn't come with OS X by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install Make. Most likely you do not have your operating system's toolchain installed. I believe for Mac OS X you need to install XCode, but there may be another way.

Git-specific note: You need to set your `config.mak` options. Notably, you should have `NO_TCLTK=YesPlease` if you don't have Tcl/Tk. Some other options may be necessary. Also if you don't have libcurl headers, use `NO_CURL=YesPlease` (WARNING: You won't be able to use http or https servers). If you do not have openssl headers, use `NO_OPENSSL=YesPlease`. And so on. Look in Makefile for more details.

According to the Makefile, since you are using Darwin, you need

```
NEEDS_CRYPTO_WITH_SSL=YesPlease
NEEDS_SSL_WITH_CRYPTO=YesPlease
NEEDS_LIBICONV=YesPlease
```

If you plan on using the test suite, `NO_SVN_TESTS=YesPlease` can speed up time to do so.

Consider enabling `BLK_SHA1=YesPlease` if applicable to Mac OS X. (not sure on this one)

Comment: Deleted my answer since you've covered it in more detail.

Comment: @yoda Okay. I think I covered all the corner cases in `config.mak`. In can be quite tricky. I wonder why OS X doesn't give you a toolchain by default. That's quite annoying.

Comment: Is there a reason specific reason why I should download XCode? I am new to development on the mac platform. What are its advantages?

Comment: @demondeac11 Don't ask me. I use Linux for development and believe its strictly superior, but I'm biased. Apparently you can strip down your XCode install to get just the bare minimum. MacPorts also seems to be an option for a toolchain.

Comment: @demondeac11 the XCode installer contains most of the development tools you normally need. This includes GNU make, among others

Comment: `BLK_SHA1=1` means using git's own optimized SHA1 implementation, instead of using OpenSSL's SHA1 implementation

Answer (score 2):

Did you install XCode?

On a side note, why are you compile it yourself instead of using the precompiled binaries or installing from a package manager such as [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)?

Comment: No I have not installed XCode, I am new to the Mac platform and I didn't know that I needed an extra $5 app to start developing rails projects. What are the benefits of XCode?

Comment: @demondeac11 You only need Xcode if you want to compile source.  Git is available as a binary package install from Google as mentioned by @superfell.

Comment: You can get XCode version 3.x for free from the Apple developer website http://developer.apple.com/. The XCode installer is bundled with development tools that you will most likely need when developing on a Mac platform. Even if you don't use the IDE itself, you'll want to install XCode just to setup the development toolchain.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason why you're trying to build from source instead of using the [packaged installer](http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/) ?

Comment: I am going through the rails installation guides, and am trying to follow the steps provided by Michael Hartl. I used the package installer but was running into some issues trying to get git to work correctly so I decided to do it from source like he does